# Set theory - Functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$X$ and $Y$ are sets, a function from $X$ to $Y$ is a relation $f$ such that $\text{dom}\,f=X$ and such that for each $x$ in $X$ there is a unique element $y$ in $Y$ with $(x,y)$ belongs to $f$.

if

$X=\{1,2\},\,Y=\{4,5,6\}$

Does $f = \{(1,4),(2,5)\}$?

Comment: On this scale, you should be able to verify this yourself.

Comment: Your $f$ is indeed a function $X\to Y$ (if that's what you meant to ask). There are more, though.

Comment: Okay thanks. So another function could be {(1,5),(2,6)}?

Comment: Yes. There are $|Y|^{|X|}=3^2=9$ functions $X\to Y$ in total, and a notation for this set of functions is $Y^X$.